# Binding multiple UITextField to a class props with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am willing to use RxSwift for MVVM binding between model values & view controllers. I want to bind my form fields to my class properties. For example:

```
struct UserDetail {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var nickName: String?
    var email: String?
    var nationalId: String?
    var birthday: String?


    init?() {}
}
```

and now I want to bind an instance of this class to my UITextFields and I define it in my ViewModel like this:

```
var userData = UserDetail()
userData.firstName = "myFirstName"

var userDetail = BehaviorSubject<UserDetail?>(value: userData)
```

and at this moment i dont have no idea to how should implement my ViewController.

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you want exactly?

Comment: I'm new with RxSwift and I want two-way binding for my TextFields. I mean that my TextFields get value in initialize of my VC and then when my fields change my instance of the class could update too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might probably be a better idea to bind each property separately, rather than an entire `UserDetail` object, but if you have to do so, then you can try something like this in your view controller:

```swift
// bind to view:
Observable.combineLatest(
    myView.firstNameTextField.rx.text,
    myView.lastNameTextField.rx.text,
    myView.nickNameTextField.rx.text,
    myView.emailTextField.rx.text,
    myView.nationalIdTextField.rx.text,
    myView.birthdayTextField.rx.text
)
.map {
    let userDetail = UserDetail()
    userDetail.firstName = $0
    userDetail.lastName = $1
    userDetail.nickName = $2
    userDetail.email = $3
    userDetail.nationalId = $4
    userDetail.birthday = $5
    return userDetail
}
.bind(to: viewModel.userDetail)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)

// bind to viewModel:
viewModel.userDetail
    .map { $0.firstName }
    .distinctUntilChanged()  // you may consider omitting this part
    .bind(to: myView.firstNameTextField.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

viewModel.userDetail
    .map { $0.lastName }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .bind(to: myView.lastNameTextField.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// ... and so on
```